# Java: how to generate a random signal in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, math, signal-processing

How do I go about generating a random signal using Java? I want to simulate a sensor to do some testing on a Android app I am working on. This signal would be sent to a server and the app will retrieve it and process it.

A photo speaks a thousand words:
[image: random signal example]

The Android random class alone isn't a good approach. But maybe with an algorithm using the random class?

Edit: more info

This signal needs to be linear and time dependent. Think of how the speed of a vehicle varies in the city, something like that.

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: Whatever data you used to create that picture seems like it ought to work.  Why not just use it?

Comment: That was from Google Images :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after giving it some thought I came up with a solution for this. I used a Sigmoid function to generate a random signal. Here is my final result:

**Final Result**
[image: Final result]

**SOLUTION**

A Sigmoid function varies from 0 to 1, or -1 to 1, depending on how you want to use it. They are pretty cool in my opinion. Here is its [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) and here is what it looks like:

[image: Sigmoid Function]

In this case to generate the random signal I used the hyperbolic tangent function `tanh` (Sigmoid):

```
tanh(x) = [ e^x - e^-x ] / [ e^x + e^-x ]
```

First I use a random function to pick a number from -2000 to 2000 and divided it by a 1000 to get a decimal value from -2 to 2. If you look at the graph, the hyperbolic function varies greatly between -2 and 2, so it gives it a nicely distributed data. I take the hyperbolic function of the random value, multiply it by a constant of proportionality (that controls the rate of change). The value of this is then added to the last known value. Last step is to take its absolute value, in case you don't want negative values.

Pseudo code:

```
y0 = 10 // initial value
k = 5 // rate of change

for ( 1 thousand points: do this ) {

    random = rand(-2000, 2000) / 1000;
    x = tanh(random);
    y = k * x + y0;
    data[] = y;

    y0 = y;
}
```

And that is it, simple and efficient.

**Edit:**

In case someone is interested or perhaps looking for some random signal, I found this [Artificial Sensor Feed](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/realtime-data-streams/sensor-network/) from PubNub, it could also be a solution a random signal.

**Another Example**

Another example of final result for x0 (initial value) = 100 and rate of change = 10.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why a sigmoid function is necessary for this; you could try a "random walk" approach - iteratively increment the value by a random (but *small*) amount

Comment: Yeh, there are many approaches to this. I first started using the sigmoid to get a random percentage from the start value and add/subtract from it, that could work too. It just worked the way it did, and since it is only for testing an app it will do for now.